# How can I read gzip compressed grib files in R?

Tags: r, grib

I am trying to open MUlti-sensor precipitation data  from eumetsat in R. I can get these data only using GZIP compression method and data format type is GRIB. When I download data I get tar file.
How can I open these data in R?
I tried to use code

```
> untar("1098496-1of1")
```

but got error message

```
Error in gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(path.expand(tarfile), "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file '1098496-1of1', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

> but I when I use next code:

```
> dir.create("rainfalldataeumetstatR") 
> getwd() 
[1] "C:/Users/st/Documents" 
> untar("1098496-1of1.tar")
> untar("1098496-1of1.tar", files="rainfalldataeumetstatR")
> list.files("rainfalldataeumetstatR")
```

I don't get some files in my directory and get answer:

```
character(0)
```

May be that error appears because files in tar zip are gz archives?

Comment: Verify you're in the correct directory with `getwd()`.

Comment: I have already done it, and I get 
[1] "C:/Users/st/Documents", and my file is in the same directory... Full name of my g=file is 1098496-1of1 and type of file is WinRAR archive (.tar). May be problem is with name of file?

Comment: Oh yeah, then you'll need to pass `"1098496-1of1.tar"` to the function

Comment: This is not really an R question but a naive-windows-or-mac-user question. You need to pay attention to the content of error messages. It R says it cannot find the file, you need to believe the message and solve that problem.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use next code: dir.create("rainfalldataeumetstatR")
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/st/Documents"
> #ntar("1098496-1of1.tar")
> untar("1098496-1of1.tar", files="rainfalldataeumetstatR")
> list.files("rainfalldataeumetstatR") I don't get some files in my directory and get answer:
character(0)

Comment: is that because the file you're looking for isn't in the tarball? Try `untar("1098496-1of1.tar"); list.files()`, or `untar("1098496-1of1.tar",list=TRUE)` ...

Comment: I tried to run untar("1098496-1of1.tar",list=TRUE) , but I got a list with 284 gz files. I can't understand how can I open them to one data frame? List looks like  untar("1098496-1of1.tar",list=TRUE)
  [1] "MSG1-SEVI-MSGMPEG-0100-0100-20130101235500.000000000Z-1098496.gz"
  [2] "MSG1-SEVI-MSGMPEG-0100-0100-20130101235000.000000000Z-1098496.gz"
  [3] "MSG1-SEVI-MSGMPEG-0100-0100-20130101234500.000000000Z-1098496.gz"
...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I untar my files using cygwin also because the wgrib package in cygwin will allow you to get an inventory file so you can tell R what data is contained in each layer. Under the assumption the data is grib1 r can read it directly. Grib2 requires wgrib2 on your machine, RNomads is working on that challenge.

Alright I recently found a great website that shows how to install wgrib so that it can run in R in conjunction with rNOMADS.

https://bovineaerospace.wordpress.com/2015/04/26/how-to-install-rnomads-with-grib-file-support-on-windows/#comments

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have grappled with opening GRIB files in R.  You have several problems and can tackle them one by one.

For the untar and gzip issues, work from the command line.  I don't know how the tar package is built/packaged from Eumetsat; does it create a directory and put all the data files in that directory?  In that case, put the tarball in a top-level data directory and then

> tar xvf tar_file_name
>   cd (to the directory that was just created)
>   gunzip *.gz
>   Note down the full path name of the files you will want to open for later use.

Are the files in GRIB1 or GRIB2?  If in GRIB1, you need to install wgrib.  If in GRIB2, you need to install wgrib2.  Both are available from NCEP.

You can download them from:
http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/

In R, 3.1 and later, you install the rNOMADS package 2.0.1 and later.
NOAA National Operational Model Archive and Distribution System (NOMADS) distributes global grid data in GRIB format (currently in GRIB2).

rNOMADS helps you open GRIB1 and GRIB2 data in R by calling wgrib or wgrib2 to decode the binary GRIB data and pipe it (in csv format) for R to read in.

Open up R, load up rNOMADS, and then call the ReadGrib routine using the full path name of your data file in "data_file_name".  This is not the way described in the rNOMADS documentation, but it works.

Installing wgrib and wgrib2 is the only hard part and it may not even be that hard, depending on your system.  I'm writing tutorials on how to install wgrib, wgrib2 and use rNOMADS with local data files.  When I am done, they will be posted here:

http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds083.2/#!software

Now for some bad news:
You need to open each file sequentially.  But, you can extract and save the subfields you need, and then read in the next datafile, overwriting the large data structure into which you read the previous file.  If that is too much of a PITA, have you considered using the GRADS tool for displaying GRIB data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to read grib files into R.  Use wgrib or wgrib2 depending on whether your file is in grib or grib2 format.  I am the package manager for rNOMADS - and trust me, we tried to figure out a simple R way, and ended up dropping it.  Maybe the folks at NCEP will do it someday, but it's out of our skill range.